# Scheduled tasks when replicating servers

Tags: load-balancing, replication, failover

Currently we have a single server that is serving customers and we've planned to add a new server and setup load balancing and database active cluster, so in this case both servers would act the same.
We have some scheduled tasks like getting some info from providers and filling our database with that data; When setting up replica, where should these jobs be done?
I cannot do these jobs on both servers because our providers charge us for transactions on their API and If I put these jobs on a single server, in case of server failure we lose some functionalities.
What are practices for this problem?

Comment: Use a distributed scheduler like Nomad.

Comment: what are you planning to use for data replication?

Answer (score 0):

The details will depend on your database server and load balancing software but basically what you need to do is find a way to add the second server without any downtime and also start the replication tasks. Here's an example with mysql: https://plusbryan.com/mysql-replication-without-downtime

The above does have one step where you have to restart the mysql server so that might be an issue. There are also options for using multi-master then adding a slave and decommissioning the master. If you can I would spend time researching this throughly and have some test setup. The things you need to make sure you have are 1) latest backup of the database 2) scripts and procedures ready 3) a fall back and contingency plan 4) also prepare for reduced performance during the initial setup and replication process.

Comment: My databases would be active-active so they are always working together. The tasks that I mentioned are some scripts that connect to a web service and fill the database. I think you've got it wrong